# PHP 7 sqlsrv_fetch_array function returns Latin1 VARCHAR strings as UTF, NOT the required Latin1

Tags: php, sql-server

The "sqlsrv_fetch_array" function is returning character strings as UTF-8, not Latin1.

The string data stored in a MS SQL SERVER is in Latin1.  When database tools MS VS, AquaDataStudio, etc. display the VARCHAR data, it displays as Latin1, which is the data type in the database.  Existing PHP 5 code (which uses FreeTDS) also displays the data correctly.  This is important because some fields contain binary data stored in a Base128 encoding scheme that uses single-byte printing characters in the range 128-255 decimal, with the PHP ORD function used to decode to VARCHAR strings.

Now we have to move to PHP 7, and the Microsoft drivers (functions beginning with "sqlsrv", like "sqlsrv_connect", "sqlsrv_query", "sqlsrv_fetch_array", etc.) are being used, and they are NOT returning the strings (VARCHAR) as Latin 1, but as multi-byte UTF-8, and of course this has two implications:
1) the character strings returned are much longer than the original strings, so the validation checks fail and/or the strings are truncated, and
2) the PHP ORD function only returns the correct value for characters in the 0-127 decimal range, so the decoding/decryption code fails.

I created a table in a local database in PHP 5 that contains records for each character in the range 1-255.  When I read the records back in PHP 5 and display the characters and their "ORD()" value, I see the correct results.  A PHP 7 version of the code displays the characters in the 1-127 range correctly, but 128-255 show as question marks, one-byte characters with the wrong ORD() value, or two or three byte strings where the "ORD" value returned is incorrect.

It appears that the problem is that the "sqlsrv_fetch_array" function forces any character string data into UTF-8, and returns only UTF-8.

Changing to UTF-8 is not an option as the data is not ours, and we have only read access to the databases.

Additionally, the application is more than half a million lines of PHP 5 code, so trying to go through and use iconv() on every field returned from every query isn't practical.

How can we get Latin1 data returned in PHP 7 from a database where the data is actually stored in Latin1?

In PHP 7 using the Microsoft "sqlsrv" functions, nothing I've tried so far works.  Some of the things I've tried are:

```
    SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS','CodePage')
```

… has no effect, probably because that is the database's default.

```
    SELECT * FROM z_php5_charset ORDER BY id
    COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

… returns an error saying "Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause."
changing to:

```
    COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

… returned the same error.

Thinking it might have something to do with the "mbstring" settings in the php.ini file, we installed the module, tried at least a dozen settings involving variations of "English" and "ISO-8859-1" from everything set to "English" to everything set to "ISO-8859-1", restarting Apache between each combination test, and while I saw a few less question marks for some combinations, the output was still UTF-8.

```
    mb_internal_encoding('ISO-8859-1');
```

… also had no effect.

It appears that the problem is that the "sqlsrv_fetch_array" function forces any character string data into UTF-8, and returns only UTF-8.

```
Minimum code (PHP 7 version)
…
    mb_internal_encoding('ISO-8859-1');
    $db_con = @sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);
    $sql = "SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS','CodePage'); ".
       // 'COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS '.
       "\n";
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM z_php5_charset ORDER BY id '.
       // 'COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS '.
       "\n";
    $result_id = sqlsrv_query($db_con, $sql, $parms, $options);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_id, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $c = $row['id'];
       $char = $row['charset'];
       $outbuf = $c.': '.$char.'  '.ord($char);
       if (strlen($char) > 1) {
          $outbuf .= ' --- more than one char returned ['.strlen($char).' chars returned]';
       }
       echo $outbuf."\n";
    }  // end while
```

```
Please note:  

Column 1 is the ORDinal value of the character written to the VARCHAR field in the database by a PHP program.

Column 2 is the character returned when retrieved from the database.

Column 3 is the value returned by the PHP ORD() function.

column 4 (if any) is additional information about the character retrieved.

    Sample of PHP 5 output:
    160: †  160
    161: °  161
    162: ¢  162
    163: £  163
    164: §  164
    165: •  165
    166: ¶  166
    167: ß  167
    168: ®  168
    169: ©  169
    170: ™  170
    171: ´  171
    172: ¨  172
    173: ≠  173
    174: Æ  174
    175: Ø  175
    176: ∞  176
    177: ±  177
    178: ≤  178
    179: ≥  179


    Sample of PHP 7 output:
    160: Â   194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    161: Â¡  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    162: Â¢  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    163: Â£  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    164: Â¤  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    165: Â¥  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    166: Â¦  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    167: Â§  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    168: Â¨  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    169: Â©  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    170: Âª  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    171: Â«  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    172: Â¬  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    173: Â­  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    174: Â®  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    175: Â¯  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    176: Â°  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    177: Â±  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    178: Â²  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
    179: Â³  194 --- more than one char returned [2 chars returned]
```

Comment: Unless you're using SQL Server 2019 then the string we not be UTF-8, SQL Server doesn't support it; and 2019 only does in UTF-8 collations.

Comment: Is it the same for other sqlsrv_* functions? Shot in the dark since I don't use sqlsrv_*, but did you verify $connectionInfo didn't have the CharacterSet set to UTF-8? I mean, it does sound like it may be a problem on the PHP side rather than the server, but can't say for sure. Likewise, did you try setting the CharacterSet to SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR in case it made a difference? Just shooting in the dark tbh.

Comment: Based on your "PHP 5 output" that isn't ISO Latin 1. Your first step would be to determine what character set you're using. Next would be finding a way to convert from that set. You haven't provided enough information here to know what the problem is. Also note that collation is nothing to do with character set. It only determines how data is sorted.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back - an "emergency" came up, but now I'm back on this. There are over 170 databases involved, and they range from 2008 to 2017, with the majority 2012.  At this point none of the databases are using Azure or 2019.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the "CharacterSet" connection option set to "SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR" to the $connectiontInfo array for sqlsrv_connect returned the error message "The encoding 'SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR' is not a supported encoding for the CharacterSet connection option."  I thought maybe I had a typo so I looked at the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-2017 and there I only see two options:  UTF-8 and SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR.

Comment: RE. Latin1... Okay, Chrome shows the characters one way.  Firefox shows the same characters.  Edge shows the characters as they appear one the Wikipedia Latin1 page.  IE shows the same characters at Edge.  Opera shows the same list I posted.  I hadn't noticed that the different browsers were showing different character sets.  (big sigh)  IIRC the headings can specify the character set.  I guess I'll try writing headers for ISO-8859-1.